# Vlookup or better alternative for retrieving column D into Column N if C contains

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

CONTEXT

- Sheet 1, Column L has a combination of numbers and letters (internal reference) - e.g. 32948/78TPL
- Sheet 2, Column C CONTAINS Column L (sheet1) - e.g. Payment proof for 32948/78TPL sent by Tom.
- Sheet 2, Column D contains time/date

WHAT I WOULD LIKE TO ACHIEVE

- Retrive on Sheet 1 Column N, the value of Column D where Column C (both from Sheet2) contains the value of Column L (sheet1)
- Basically retrieve the time/date column from Sheet 2 for the correct row on Sheet1

WHAT I'VE TRIED
`VLOOKUP("*"&$L7&"*",(Sheet12!C2:F),{3},false),"")`

WHAT HAPPENS

- It does return the correct value but works only for that row
- If I change to `VLOOKUP("*"&$L7:$L&"*",(Sheet12!C2:F),{3},false),"")` it returns some strange values like "43984.76019" where the time/date cell should return values like "6/2/2020 18:14:40". So the range can't be assigned like that and probably the problem is trying to use a range with wildcards which I think it's not possible
- If I manually stretch the formula (1st version) it returns wrong values for rows where Column L is empty

Is VLOOKUP the way to go?
Can someone please point me to a better direction?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(L2:L, {REGEXEXTRACT(Sheet2!C2:C, 
 TEXTJOIN("|", 1, L2:L)), Sheet2!D2:D}, 2, 0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Worked like a charm! The strange numbers did appear again but I just had to change the cell format, but the empty ones now stay empty. Thank you! Will try to figure out what you did in detail